# Cannot get Jenkins to update GitHub Pull Request with a build status

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, github-api

I am using the Jenkins plugin *GitHub Pull Request Builder* to run some commands, and then update the status of my Pull Request.

The job is correctly triggering when I update a PR on GitHub, however I cannot get the job to update the status of the build on GitHub.

I have closely replicated the steps outlined in this article: https://medium.com/@mreigen/integrate-jenkins-builds-into-github-pull-requests-33bc053d6210

When I check the System Logs, I see this error: `GitHub project property is missing the URL, cannot start ghprb trigger for job`

I have entered the URL everywhere I can find to enter it, but so far nothing has worked.

This is my configuraiton for the plugin:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help on how to get the job to successfully add a status message to the Pull Request on GitHub would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the `GitHub Pull Request Builder` section of the Build Triggers, enabling the checkbox: 
**Build every pull request automatically without asking** enables the Jenkins job to add an update status to GitHub.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the github project option  and provide your gihub url there.

[image: Refer below screenshot]